Asymptotic growth of the Fibonacci primes
Define $\kappa(n)$ to be the number of prime Fibonacci numbers less than $F_n$. Is it the case that $\kappa(n) \sim a\log(n)$ for some constant $a$?
I know that $F_n$ prime $\implies n$ prime (except for $F_4$), but the converse does not hold. Hence, $\kappa(n)$ cannot grow any quicker than $\frac{n}{\ln(n)}$. Looking at the graph suggests maybe that $\kappa(n) \sim a\log(n)$ for some constant $a$, however only about 50 Fibonacci primes are known, making it hard to conjecture about the asymptotic growth from purely graphical observations.
Can anything more precise be said about this asymptotic growth?

It's even an open problem if $\kappa(n)$ is bounded or not.
